# File permission displayed a lot question marks in docker container

Tags: linux, docker, file-permissions

I wrote a Dockerfile, the last contents are

```
RUN echo "root:root" | chpasswd
RUN echo "beakerx:beakerx" | chpasswd
RUN usermod -aG sudo beakerx

RUN echo beakerx | sudo -S chown -R beakerx:beakerx /home/beakerx/.local
RUN echo beakerx | sudo -S find /home/beakerx/.local -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
RUN echo beakerx | sudo -S find /home/beakerx/.local -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

RUN id
RUN ls -la /home/beakerx/.local
RUN ls -la /home/beakerx/.local/share

USER beakerx

RUN id
RUN ls -la /home/beakerx/.local
RUN ls -la /home/beakerx/.local/share
```

When I build this image, it gave me the following errors.

```
Step 17/29 : RUN echo "root:root" | chpasswd
 ---> Running in b07756b764ef
 ---> 11a182191463
Removing intermediate container b07756b764ef
Step 18/29 : RUN echo "beakerx:beakerx" | chpasswd
 ---> Running in 2f2bc836b1af
 ---> dee6ebdf5b9c
Removing intermediate container 2f2bc836b1af
Step 19/29 : RUN usermod -aG sudo beakerx
 ---> Running in 8a1ccfffd565
 ---> d7815406e070
Removing intermediate container 8a1ccfffd565
Step 20/29 : RUN echo beakerx | sudo -S chown -R beakerx:beakerx /home/beakerx/.local
 ---> Running in 19aebc73f517
 ---> a8cb84a563c5
Removing intermediate container 19aebc73f517
Step 21/29 : RUN echo beakerx | sudo -S find /home/beakerx/.local -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
 ---> Running in 7c2434fa279a
 ---> 5ce4b0b0e859
Removing intermediate container 7c2434fa279a
Step 22/29 : RUN echo beakerx | sudo -S find /home/beakerx/.local -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
 ---> Running in 5f57457f1fe5
 ---> 1bb42b3ef8f3
Removing intermediate container 5f57457f1fe5
Step 23/29 : RUN id
 ---> Running in 101209499f50
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
 ---> e45945b090ab
Removing intermediate container 101209499f50
Step 24/29 : RUN ls -la /home/beakerx/.local
 ---> Running in d337b58c1571
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  6 beakerx beakerx 4096 Sep  7 01:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 beakerx beakerx 4096 Sep  7 01:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 beakerx beakerx 4096 Sep  7 01:30 share
 ---> 7fd474369e15
Removing intermediate container d337b58c1571
Step 25/29 : RUN ls -la /home/beakerx/.local/share
 ---> Running in e05cd55aaae6
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 6 beakerx beakerx 4096 Sep  7 01:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 beakerx beakerx 4096 Sep  7 01:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x 6 beakerx beakerx 4096 Sep  7 01:30 jupyter
 ---> 03191c2d9fc8
Removing intermediate container e05cd55aaae6
Step 26/29 : USER beakerx
 ---> Running in 40b2d522ea0f
 ---> 604503b2152b
Removing intermediate container 40b2d522ea0f
Step 27/29 : RUN id
 ---> Running in e7b8ed6a1165
uid=1000(beakerx) gid=1000(beakerx) groups=1000(beakerx),27(sudo)
 ---> 5987e9d9f0bb
Removing intermediate container e7b8ed6a1165
Step 28/29 : RUN ls -la /home/beakerx/.local
 ---> Running in 4c65bd4a383e
ls: cannot access '/home/beakerx/.local/share': Permission denied
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  6 beakerx beakerx 4096 Sep  7 01:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 beakerx beakerx 4096 Sep  7 01:30 ..
d?????????  ? ?       ?          ?            ? share
ERROR: Service 'beakerx-cling-prebuild' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c ls -la /home/beakerx/.local' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

That's quite strange, I can see the right permission using root, but a lot of question marks using other users. When I removed these debugging code and run this docker image, it gave me `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/beakerx/.local/share/jupyter/runtime'` errors.

I have searched a lot on the Internet, but couldn't found some helpful info about this.

Comment: I saw these question marks (and got some errors) when running an image with Docker 18.03.1-ce. Running the very same image with Docker 20.1.3 did not show the question marks and worked well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very weird [bug in older docker versions](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20690). It happens if the first user that access the directory is non-root. Just change the order of the commands to access the dir as user.

Run something like  `ls /home/beakerx/`, before issuing `USER beakerx`.

It worked for me.